# I am getting response from php but not printing in text box

Tags: php, jquery

I have two files, one for HTML and jQuery and other is for PHP.
I am getting response from PHP page, but I am not able to display in a HTML text box.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fill_amt()
{
  var sname=$("#sname").val();
  $.post("try_insert.php",{sname:sname,cmd2:"fill_amt"},function(data){
  $("#tot_amt").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="tot_amt" name="tot_amt">
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$sql = mysql_query("select total_fee from admission where first_name='".$sname."'")or die(mysql_query());
$val=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$tot=$val;
echo json_encode($tot);
```

Comment: Use `$("#tot_amt").val(data);` instead of `$("#tot_amt").html(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`$("#tot_amt").val(data);` 
instead of 
`$("#tot_amt").html(data);`

Also format your json data correctly.

Comment: @MarcGiroux Thanks

Comment: yeah its work but it will display in double inverted comma in to textbox

Comment: @NehaSutariya You need to properly parse the json data

Comment: @NehaSutariya "double inverted comma"? Do you mean quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fill_amt()
{
  var sname=$("#sname").val();
  $.post("try_insert.php",{sname:sname,cmd2:"fill_amt"},function(data){
     var json=JSON.parse(data); // parsing data form JSON string and convert it into object
     $("#tot_amt").val(json.total);
  });
}
</script>
```

PHP code should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("select total_fee from admission where first_name='".$sname."'")or die(mysql_query());
$val=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$tot=$val['total'];
echo json_encode(array("total"=>$tot)); // give response as json string
```

Comment: Can you explain the solution ? where are the errors ? so the OP can understand what you fixed.

Comment: You can also just set `dataType` to `json` and the [jQuery POST request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) parses it automatically.